# Is it correct to consider Delphi's Format() function as an alternative to wsprintf()?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I want to know if it is correct to consider Delphi's [`Format()`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=format) function to be an alternative to [`wsprintf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfa)?

I want to produce the same output as this:

```
wsprintf( nameFile, "%s_%d_%08x.pfx", nameStore, c_certs, GetTickCount());
```

[Reference](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/69367908/)

In Delphi, I'm trying to use this:

```
// Where "Mem" is a TMemoryStream variable
Mem.SaveToFile(NameStore + '_' + IntToStr(I) + '_' + Format('%08x', [GetTickCount]) + '.pfx');
```

Am I'm on the right track?

Comment: Yes, they are similar. You could make the  Delphi code look even more like the original, but it should work like this. Did you compile and run? Did it work? What is your actual question?

Comment: @GolezTrol, `You could make the Delphi code look even more like the original`, yes, i already made this, [**see**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614210/how-export-all-my-certificates-of-software-separately-to-a-pfx-file). `Did you compile and run? Did it work?` No, because i'm still not had buy a certificate to store in 'MY' store. The code of previous question compiles fine, but i not have sure that is 100% working (because i still not have a certificate of software in 'MY' location).

Comment: You don't need any certificate to test whether or not you can format a string. The C++ code operates on text, not certificates. The skill of debugging lies in breaking things into component parts.

Comment: OK thank you, this question already was overcomed. Now someone could analise [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614210/how-export-all-my-certificates-of-software-separately-to-a-pfx-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) my previous question and give a suggestion or point some error (if exists) please? I was sad that no one answered my previous question :-(. And now i saw a downvote on my possible solution that i inserted as answer. Please, someone could say what's wrong on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be the most suitable alternative. You can come pretty close to the same exact syntax.

```
wsprintf( nameFile, "%s_%d_%08x.pfx", nameStore, c_certs, GetTickCount() );
```

Delphi code:

```
NameFile := Format('%s_%d_%.8x.pfx', [namestore, i, GetTickCount]);
```

Comment: ok, thank you. I want know why no one answered my previous question linked here :D. But i think that i followed correctly the suggestion gave on comment. You already worked with Digital Certificate programaticaly in Delphi?

Comment: If I had an answer for your other question, I would have posted an answer to it. :-)

Comment: ok, i know, i undestood. But independent thi question here,you could see my previous question and say me of some error or something to make better code please?

Comment: I changed the code. In Delphi's Format, `%08x` doesn't work (it does not left-pad with zeroes). You'll have to use `%.8x`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yep, you're correct. Didn't look close enough. Thanks for the fix.